# Polygonizer Error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isMultipart' See log for more details"

Tags: qgis, error, qgis-processing

I'm trying to polygonize. But I'm getting an error message:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isMultipart' See log for more
>   details

Basically what I'm trying to do is divide the city into blocks so I can assign a value to each block.

I'm not sure if I'm getting the error because of something about the lines or someting in the attribute table... Or something else.

Here's a closeup of what the street centerlines look like.

[image]

Maybe I need to clean up the lines or something, not sure. But anyway here's the error message I get when I run it.

[image]

Comment: What's the error you encounter?  Please [edit] your question to include the error message text in full (not as an image).

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: Actually the log is in the image, that's where the error message is. I'm not sure why the log says to check the log. Unless there's another log I don't know about.

Comment: @GDog It is a classical error message. The problem is clear: there is a feature that is not recognized. Did you follow the steps explained in my answer?

Answer (score 3):

From [Python: Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949265/7272497):

> NoneType means that instead of an instance of whatever Class or Object
>   you think you're working with, you've actually got None. That usually
>   means that an assignment or function call up above failed or returned
>   an unexpected result.

This means that there are probably some features (geometries) that are not valid. You may check your input layer using the **Check validity** algorithm available from the Processing Toolbox and then try again to run the **Polygonize** tool. It will allow you to repair any eventually *invalid* geometry.

If it still doesn't work, you may also try the **Lines to polygon** tool or the **Convert lines to polygons** SAGA tool, which are both available from the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57945/discussion-on-answer-by-mgri-polygonizer-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribu).

Comment: I tried the Check Validity tool, and cleaned up any invalid lines I could find, then I used the Convert Lines to Polygons tool and it ran great!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, and discovered that I had lines with a 'NULL' length. I identified these using the field calculator and calculating the $length field, then deleting all lines with a 'NULL' length.

After this the Polygonize tool worked.

Comment: Can you explain how you did that please?  I have the same issue as the OP on here, and I'd like to peruse this line of inquiry to see if this is the answer I need.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Point.shp when I tried to calculate X,Y coordinate. I found that ONE empty row was created (by mistake) in the file that actually had no geometry. So I deleted that empty row and then calculated XY.